# UIWebView to display both local image and facebook comment

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, uiwebview

I'm facing an issue on an UIWebView.
I got a WebView which display an html string. This html string contains :

- Html text
- Local images
- fb:comments

At first i only had Html + local Image so I was using th well known method :

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[webview loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

Everything worked perfectly.
But then i had to implement facebook comments http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Since my old BaseURL wasn't working anymore for facebook i tried to load with

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com/"];
```

This made my facebook work but the local image aren't displayed within the webview, even with absolute path.

Any help would be appreciate. Thanks for your time

Comment: Through my trials with something similar I was unable to get a web view to reference both local and web based content at the same time. It was a one or the other, not both situation. Hopefully someone will have an answer to this or at least confirm if it's just not possible.

Comment: @Mark Reid it is partially possible, see the links below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a solution to use the `img` tag with base64 encoded image data instead of the url.
That should not be a problem as you have the image locally, see the html [sample](http://www.sourcepod.com/ezqkig43-7534).

To test it quickly you can use the online encoding [service](http://www.abluestar.com/utilities/encode_base64/index.php) (50kb limitation)

The original answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568431/without-using-baseurl-can-we-add-local-images-in-the-uiwebview)

---

And the truncated base64-sample for future reference:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
FB1
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                    appId      : null,
                    channelUrl : null,
                    status     : true,
                    cookie     : true,
                    xfbml      : true 
                    });

        };

        (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
         }(document));
        </script>

    FB2
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh......lAmeQ/IAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="Screen Shot 2012-05-23 at 6.53.28 AM.png" />

    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://facebook.com" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>

</body>
</html>
```